# Access is Denied - Certreq.exe

Tags: windows, permissions, certificate, ssl-certificate, certificate-authority

I am getting an "access is denied" message when attempting to use the certreq from the commandline.

TLDR; I am a domain admin, and a local admin on the machine (inherited). I am using an elevated session of the command prompt. I have searched the internet, and seemingly the only thing helpful was to make sure that admins have full control over `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys`.

I did that, and I am still getting permission denied, even after a reboot.

Comment: Can you provide the exact error message you recieved.  You shouldn't have to change or modify the permissions of `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys`, in fact modifying the permissions of that folder, could be connected to the behavior you describe.

Comment: Please add the actual certreq command you're using too - `certreq -enroll` is very different from `certreq -sign` for example. You can have access denied to in/out files, the keystores, the CA server, or the particular template.